# Cannot make a boarder from left to right covered

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to make a boarder for my website so the icons have a box around them from left to right. I want something like this:
[image: 1]]
But for me, it doesnt seem to work and this is the outcome using similar css.
[image: 2]]
If anyone could help me find out what I am doing wrong would be highly appreciated. My code is below.

CSS:
https://hastebin.com/umibawufuw.css

HTML:
https://hastebin.com/wogacayoko.html

I would love any help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try like this**

```css
#logo{
  background: #3cf;
  min-height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.border{
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: block;
  min-height: 100px;
  border-top: 2px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
.buttons{
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.buttons .button{
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  margin: 1% auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="layout">
    <div id="logo">LOGO IMG HERE</div>
    <div class="border">
      <div class="buttons">
        <div class="button" id="forum">Block 1</div>
        <div class="button" id="vote">Block 2</div>
        <div class="button" id="store">Block 3</div>
        <div class="button" id="bans">Block 4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Note : Add `margin`,`padding` and more CSS property as your need.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/435d2cfa7f2586c6d170b0ae55599999
Didn't do much just the same as before

Comment: Remove 'width:1000px;' from ID `#layout`. Make it `100%` @SimonMitchell

Comment: That was easier than I thought. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript to set the width of a wrapping div element to  the width of screen (specifically, window.innerWidth), apply the border styling to it, and then set the menu's margin to auto (that is, margin:auto;).  Then you can adjust the height of the wrapping div by setting the menu's padding-top and padding - bottom to taste.